# Hide the legend form barchart label in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I deal with simple problem, after I added color mapping by Y value in labels  have been added new value whichis useless from me. Is there any way to delete this?

```
        fig1=px.bar(europe_df1, x="Month End Date", y="Monthly Return",
        color=europe_df1["Monthly Return"] > 0,color_discrete_map= 
        {True: "green", False: "red"},)
        fig1.update_layout({
        'plot_bgcolor':' rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        'paper_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        'font_color':'white',
        'showlegend':False,
        })
```

[I would like to remove the 'color' label and keep only X and Y values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHJSS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be another solution that is best, but we can retrieve the graph data and update it to exclude unnecessary strings. I have modified the example in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#bar-chart-with-plotly-express) since the data is not presented.

```
import plotly.express as px

data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")

fig = px.bar(data_canada,
             x='year',
             y='pop',
             color=data_canada['pop'] > 20_000_000,
             color_discrete_map={True: "green", False: "red"},
            )
fig.update_layout({
        'plot_bgcolor':' rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        'paper_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        'font_color':'white',
        'showlegend':False,
        })

hovertext = fig.data[0]['hovertemplate']
htext = hovertext.split('<br>',1)
#print(htext)
fig.data[0]['hovertemplate'] = htext[1]
fig.data[1]['hovertemplate'] = htext[1]
fig.show()
```

[image]

**If no additional settings are made**

[image]

Comment: it worked very well, thanks a lot